# Problems with TV-tuner (Afatech AF9015) on Xubuntu 17.10

Tags: usb, xubuntu, tv-tuner

I am having problems making this USB TV-tuner to work under Xubuntu 17.10 (works under Windows 7).

Running "lsusb" gives:

> Bus 001 Device 003: ID 15a4:9016 Afatech Technologies, Inc. AF9015
> DVB-T USB2.0 stick

Running "dmesg | grep DVB" gives:

> [    2.236699] usb 1-8: Product: DVB-T 2
>
> [    2.382657] Afatech DVB-T 2: Fixing fullspeed to highspeed interval: 10 -> 7
>
> [    2.382712] input: Afatech DVB-T 2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.1/0003:15A4:9016.0006/input/input7
>
> [    2.440134] hid-generic 0003:15A4:9016.0006: input,hidraw3: USB HID  v1.01 Keyboard [Afatech DVB-T 2] on usb-0000:00:1d.7-8/input1

Kaffeine does not find any DVB device. Any suggestions?

Comment: Open Additional Drivers, select & install the firmware for Afatech.

Comment: @MichaelBay There is no such option.

Comment: Install it manually following the instructions in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the firmware for Afatech AF9015 from [here](http://palosaari.fi/linux/v4l-dvb/firmware/af9015/5.24.0.0/) and copy it to `/lib/firmware`.

Assuming the downloaded file is in the default Downloads folder, open a Terminal and:

```
cd Downloads
sudo cp dvb-usb-af9015.fw /lib/firmware
```

The Afatech AF9015 DVB-T2 tuner show work as expected with all the programs.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a question, why do you think this device did not appear in Additional Drivers?

Comment: It used to appear. The actual firmware may have been removed from the Ubuntu repositories for reasons unknown (to me).

Comment: This just worked for me, ty! I'd forgotten that this old tuner (which I picked up for buttons years ago, but mothballed because I couldn't get it to work under Windows) only does SD (not HD) TV. But in the intervening years I've pretty much given up live broadcast TV apart from the new GB News channel - and that's not HD anyway, so suddenly my cheapo white elephant tuner turns out to be a useful bargain, thanks to Linux and this answer! :)